# Slide format getting changed when we paste a slide to new presentation

Tags: vsto, powerpoint

We are working on PowerPoint add-in application. In this application, we have a feature for programmatically create the presentation using slides. In between, we noticed an issue related to slide formatting.

The issue is, when we copy a slide in a presentation to new presentation, it seems that the slide format is getting changed.  This issue is not related our add-in application. You can see the issue in PowerPoint itself.

Original slide in the presentation
[image]

When we copy slide to the new presentation, the format seems to get changed
[image]

You can see that graph section getting changed.

When we paste the slides, we will get following options. “Use destination Theme”, “Keep Source formatting” and “Picture”.  Even if we selected the “Keep Source Formatting” option, our issue not gets resolved. When we paste the slide using “Picture” option it worked well, But we can’t edit such slides.

[image]

How do we paste the slide with the correct format and editable option? Is there any way to solve this issue? Any help would be appreciable.

Presentation link

https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1uBmQukvmY5XflMXK1-3m0YXzCp4AXSh3Jknj1E_EpQU/edit?usp=sharing